# how to create by default an instance of an object in a has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a DSL for creating an object in an AR relationship that would be the opposite of `:dependent => destroy` (in other words create an object so that it always exists). Say, for example, I have the following:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  #price
  has_one :price, :as => :pricable, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :price
  ....

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :pricable, :polymorphic => true
    attr_accessible :price, :price_comment
```

I'm thinking I'd like for a price to be created every time even if we don't specify a price? Is the only (or best) option to do this as a callback or is there a way to do this via a DSL (similar to `:denpendent => :destroy`)?

Comment: Why would you want a price object created with no price/price_comment?

Comment: see below, whether no price is free or not?

Comment: So what's the difference? If you create `Price` object with a `null` or `0.00` price, vs just not creating a price object? If you *need* a price, you should force the user to enter a price or explicitly select "free".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as there is virtually no use-case for this. If your record cannot exist without an associated record, you should probably be *preventing* the record from being saved, not shoe-horning in some kind of pseudo-null object to take its place.

The closest approximation would be a `before_save` callback:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :price, :as => :pricable, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :price

  before_save :create_default_price

  def create_default_price
    self.price ||= create_price
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only run this code one time on create and use the convenience method `create_price` here:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :price, :as => :pricable, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :price

  after_validation :create_default_price, :on => :create

  def create_default_price
    self.create_price
  end
end
```

Comment: pricable did look funky (though priceable doesn't look much better - but is certainly correct). thx.